# Unable to install OSMNX on Linux Manjaro due to ImportError

Tags: python, linux, importerror, arm64, osmnx

I am currently running Manjaro 21.1.0 and I have followed the documented installation process for osmnx, however, when attempting to run any python program with osmnx imported, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ezra/Downloads/py/Webscraper.py", line 16, in <module>
    import osmnx as ox
  File "/home/ezra/miniconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osmnx/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._api import *
  File "/home/ezra/miniconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osmnx/_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .distance import get_nearest_edge
  File "/home/ezra/miniconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import utils_geo
  File "/home/ezra/miniconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.9/site-packages/osmnx/utils_geo.py", line 12, in <module>
    from shapely.ops import split
ImportError: cannot import name 'split' from 'shapely.ops' (/home/ezra/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shapely/ops.py)
```

Is this an issue with Shapely that I am able to resolve?

Comment: Perhaps shapely didn't install correctly? You can see the missing function here: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.split It appears to be trying to import it from your local site-packages rather than from your virtual environment.

Comment: This seems to have been the case. I was able to fix it by reinstalling Shapely, and then changing the system path to the correct environment, though I am not sure which one actually fixed it. Thanks for the help!